# Unable to connect to Oracle database 21c

Tags: linux, oracle

I have fresh Oracle Linux with Oracle Database 21c installed on it.
Issue is I cannot connect to it from the outside, locally there is no problem.

lsof was showing that port 1521 was open only for IPv6, so I changed the listener.ora config to:

```
(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = linux-oracledb)(PORT = 1521)(IP=V4_ONLY))
```

lsof is showing:

```
tnslsnr   1285 oracle    9u  IPv4  27233      0t0  TCP *:1521 (LISTEN)
```

But when I'm testing the connection from another pc I have:

> TCP connect to (10.10.8.44 : 1521) failed

Firewall rules are ok.

Any idea what I am missing here?

Comment: Post the command you're using to connect and also if you can use `TNSPING` or `TRCROUTE` and post the results.

Answer (score 0):

Starting with a disclaimer here - I am not an Oracle guy so don't be hard on me. But do you know if your server is listening on 127.0.0.1, 10.10.8.44, or something else? I think you will need it to have it listen on 0.0.0.0 for receiving outside connection

Comment: Any help is really appreciated! Especially here where I'm out of ideas. :)
It's listening on 0.0.0.0
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:1521            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1288/tnslsnr

Comment: Is the other pc on the same network, or from internet?

Comment: Same network connected via VPN tunnel. Will try to reach it directly from the same network later today.